# How to configure RestTemplate to use browser's session for api call?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have an API written with Spring Boot RestControllers secured with keycloak.  I am writing a  Thymeleaf client in a separate Spring Boot application to use this API.
The browser of the client successfully logs into keycloak and on the controller I am able to access the OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal via @AuthenticationPrincipal.

How can I configure a RestTemplate to use this already established trust relationship rather than establish a new one for each RestTemplate?

The code below is the code that successfully authenticates with the api using the user authenticated in the browser.

Controller

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final ProductService productService;
    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
    // only needed to validate registration during debug
    private final InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    public ProductController(RestTemplate restTemplate, ProductService productService,
                           ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                           InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.productService = productService;
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal,
                        Authentication auth,
                        HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                        Model model) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient accessToken = clientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient("keycloak-confidential-user",
                auth, servletRequest);

    log.debug("accessToken is null [{}]", accessToken == null);
    model.addAttribute("products",
            productService.getProductWithDetailsForUser(UUID.fromString(principal.getName()), accessToken));
    return "product/list";
}
```

Service Method

```java
public List<ProductListInfo> getProductWithDetailsForUser(UUID userId, String token) {
    List<ProductListInfo> products = productRepository.findByUser_UniqueUserOrderByNameAsc(userId,
            Pageable.ofSize(10));

    if(token != null) {
        header.setBearerAuth(token);
        for (ProductListInfo product : products) {
            ProductPublicDto publicData = restTemplate.exchange(
                    "https://localhost:8043/product/%s/public".formatted(product.getProductId()),
                    HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(header), ProductPublicDto.class).getBody();
            productMapper.partialUpdateDetails(publicData product);
        }
    }
    return products;
}
```

pom.xml snip

```xml
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app with Thymeleaf controllers is configured as an OAuth2 client, the other app with REST API should be configured as an OAuth2 resource server and would probably be stateless (no session).

Requests to resource servers are authorized with Bearer access tokens, not sessions. In your client, configure your REST client (`RestTemplate` is not quite the trend, you might have a look at `WebClient` or `@FeignClient`) to set an `Authorization` header with a `Bearer` string containing the access token you get from the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` (you can have the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` autowired in your OAuth2 client controllers, and query it to retrieve the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` you need).

I have a complete working sample with `WebClient` (not `RestTemplate`, sorry) [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui). In this tutorials, the client and resource server parts are merged in a single app, but the two parts have distinct `SecurityFilterChain` beans and communicate with a REST client. Internal requests are authorized with a Bearer access token, just as you probably need.

Comment: Code above modified to include the class header and constructor.   Fails with:  `There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository`
I also tried it with the implementation class of InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository instead of the interface.

Comment: I checked the beans that Spring is instantiating on app startup and clientRegistrationRepository is listed

Comment: You already injected it as `@Controller` property (`clientRegistrationRepository`), remove it from method parameters (`clientRepository`) and use the property to retrieve the authorized client on which you should find an access token.

Comment: In case you didn't browse the code I linked by yourself, the sample `@Controller` retrieving a specific **`OAuth2AuthorizedClient` from an `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`** (not just a `ClientRegistration` from a `ClientRegistrationRepository` as done in your updated code) is there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/ui/UiController.java

Comment: I did  review the code you linked but after I updated the post.  After switching to `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`, `loadAuthorizedClient` returns a null.  Tracing through the invocation, it is because there are no AuthorizedClients for the registrationId.  I only have one registration in the project and the value I'm passing in matches the value in the map.  Based on no Authorized Clients, I think I have something wrong before the controller is called.  Reviewing the setup now.  Updated to post above for current code.

Comment: Success!  After I updated the WebSecurityConfig, I'm getting the AuthorizedClient, the access token and the api accepts the authorization!  Thanks for the great assistance and very helpful code on GitHub!!